# In which case should the `if` condition be used and in which case be `when` condition be used in QtQuick?

Tags: qt, qt-quick

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qtquick-statesanimations-states.html#the-when-property

Below is a ***when*** statement usage:

> For convenience, the State element has a when property that can bind to expressions to change the state whenever the bound expression evaluates to true. The when property will revert the state back to the default state when the expression evaluates to false.

```
Rectangle {
    id: bell
    width: 75; height: 75
    color: "yellow"

    states: State {
                name: "RINGING"
                when: (signal.state == "CRITICAL")
                PropertyChanges {target: speaker; play: "RING!"}
            }
}
```

> The bell component will change to the RINGING state whenever the signal.state is CRITICAL.

---

Below is a ***if*** statement usage:

```
onClicked: rectangleA.state == "one" ?
    rectangleA.state = "two" : rectangleA.state = "one"
```

**Question:** In which case should the ***if*** condition be used and in which case be ***when*** condition be used?

Answer (score 2):

You've mentioned two options to achieve similar effect.

First (with use of "when") is declarative way, second ("if") is imperative.

**Declarative** way uses bindings - that is (in Qt) special signals & slots mechanism to update target property every time evaluation of given expression changes; the binding itself will be active until you explicitely assign a new value or binding to that property.

**Imperative** way executes code only once when some action takes place.

Qt QUICK is a declarative language and this approach is recommended, but not all problems can be solved using it. The best you can do is to minimize imperative parts of your code where it is possible.

Generally you can think of these approaches as of (terms borrowed from electronics) *edge-triggered* and *level-triggered* execution of code - when you want to execute some code once triggered by some action (you could interpret *edge* as some event) use imperative approach and `onSomethingChanged` or `onSomethingHappened` handlers; mouse handling is such case definitely (as it's event-based).
On the other hand, if you want piece of yout code to be maintained all the time some condition is met, (*level* is not changing) - use declarative way.

It's hard to tell what approaches fit to your examples - I don't know (the first one) if you want to play just a sigle sound once on state change (then you should use `onStateChange` handler), or play the sound as long as the state of `bell` is `"RINGING"` - then declarative approach is fine. In the second snippet I would use mix of declarative and imperative (in order to minimize imperative code) and add `isInOneState` boolean property

```
property bool isInOneState: state == "one"
```

and modify handler in that way:

```
onClicked: isInOneState = !isInOneState
```

so you could bind state:

```
state: isInOneState ? "one" : "two"
```

Of course, this works for two states.

Comment: Misunderstood the question, deleted my answer, and then you got it right. Upvoted!